# What is meant by "mathematical/empirical validations" of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, validation, math, optimization

What is meant by "mathematical/empirical validations" of the algorithm ?
Thank you

Comment: Those are two different ways to show an algorithm is true. But what is the context? Where did you see this phrase? Which algorithm is mentioned here?

Comment: Hi Rory Daulton, Thank you for your attention. I applied Swarm intelligence Algorithms (Artificial Bee Colony, ACO, CS..) to solve continuous functions such as hypersphere, Rosenbrock, Griewank . So how I can give mathematical/empirical validations of the algorithm?